# Is there a useful matrix identity for this?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have:

$$ S = \left[ \begin{matrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix} \right]$$

$$ X_0 = \left[ \begin{matrix}
        a & b & c \\
        d & e & f \\
        g & h & i \\
        j & k & l \\
        \end{matrix} \right]$$

$$ X_1 = X_0S + \left[ \begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{matrix} \right]
\left[ \begin{matrix}
A & 0 & 0 \\
0 & B & 0 \\
0 & 0 & C \\
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

Suppose we know $[X_0^{T}X_0]^{-1}$.  Are there any matrix identities that would let us calculate $[X_1^{T}X_1]^{-1}$ quickly, rather than having to apply a matrix inversion algorithm to it?

I would like to generalise the result to cases where $X_0$ is $n * m$, where n and m can get very large.

Comment: Do you mean $X_1 = X_0 S + \ldots$?

Comment: Yes, I do.  I will try to edit!  Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

$X_1$ is a rank-$2$ perturbation of $X_0 R$, where $R$ is the permutation matrix
$\left[\matrix{0 & 1 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 1\cr 1 & 0 & 0\cr}\right]$.
So if we write $X_1 = X_0 R + C$, we have 
$$ X_1^T X_1 = R^T X_0^T X_0 R + C^T X_0 R + (R^T X_0^T  + C^T) C$$
where each of the last two terms has rank at most $2$,
and you can apply the Woodbury matrix identity twice: see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) .  This won't be very useful in the $3 \times 4$ case, but in a generalization where $m$ and $n$ are large it may be.